# Unknown column in WHERE clause in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have pages table which I'm trying to truncate.
I need to leave last 10 versions of each page (page is identified by `uid`).

```
id----|----uid----|----version

1 ----|---- 1 ----|---- 1

2 ----|---- 1 ----|---- 2

3 ----|---- 1 ----|---- 3

4 ----|---- 1 ----|---- 4

5 ----|---- 2 ----|---- 1

6 ----|---- 2 ----|---- 2

...........

55 ----|---- 1 ----|---- 23

56 ----|---- 2 ----|---- 14

57 ----|---- 2 ----|---- 15
```

I've tried with this MySQL query:

```
DELETE FROM pages AS p WHERE p.id IN (
    SELECT Versions.id FROM
        (SELECT q.id FROM pages AS q WHERE p.uid = q.uid ORDER BY q.version DESC LIMIT 10) 
    AS Versions
)
```

but above SQL returns:

> Unknown column 'p.uid' in 'where clause'

On Stackoverflow is loads of answers for similar questions like mine but as I'm not SQL ninja I wasn't able to convert any of these to fit my problem.
I don't want to overkill my query as well. 
There must be some simple answer to this.

I can achieve needed truncation in MSSQL Server with query below:

```
DELETE FROM pages WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT Versions.id FROM
        (SELECT TOP (10) q.id FROM pages AS q WHERE pages.uid = q.uid ORDER BY q.version DESC) 
    AS Versions
)
```

Thanks

Comment: You have no p alias in your inner query - also why the order by for delete?

Comment: Sorry I've converted this from select query which I was using for testing as didn't want to delete rows in my dev environment. I've changed this now

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to co-ordinate the queries together here; just select a list of IDs to delete- the tables are the same

```
DELETE FROM pages WHERE id NOT IN 

    (SELECT TOP (10) id FROM pages ORDER BY q.version DESC)
```

You can't "order by" a delete query..

If youre after the MySQL version, and your version of MySQL doesnt support LIMIT for subqueries, and it doesn't support window functions like this:

```
delete from pages where id in 
  (select id from 
    (select id, row_number() over(order by dt desc) as rown from pages) a where a.rown > 10) 
  )
```

then you could consider something like:

```
CREATE table x as SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY q.Version DESC LIMIT 10

TRUNCATE /*or delete from*/ pages

INSERT INTO pages SELECT * FROM x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE PG FROM pages PG
LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT  q.id FROM pages AS q ORDER BY q.version DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
 ) Versions ON Versions.ID=PG.ID
WHERE Versions.ID IS NULL
```

You can try above query.

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. Please see example table data. Thanks

Comment: @MariuszSołtys You want to delete `TOP 10` pages?

Comment: I wan to to delete all pages versions EXCEPT LAST 10 VERSIONS of each page that's why I need to reference 'uid' (See MSSQL example)

Comment: Your sub-query selects first 10 records from pages table, and not first 10 records for each page in pages table. That's why it doesn't work in my case

Comment: `SELECT  q.id FROM pages AS q ORDER BY q.version DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` will return top 10 version and i had made `LEFT JOIN` it with main table.Here i had put condition `WHERE Versions.ID IS NULL` which means i have to delete only those record which are not fetched in `INSIDETABLE` in our case `VERSION` it is.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each page is identified by `uid`. Heres is test of your example. It simply doesn't work as expected. [http://rextester.com/NPXS51058](http://rextester.com/NPXS51058)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE p FROM pages AS p WHERE p.id IN (
    SELECT Versions.id FROM
        (SELECT q.id FROM pages AS q WHERE p.uid = q.uid ORDER BY q.version DESC LIMIT 10) 
    AS Versions
)
```

Check if this works..

Comment: Unknown column 'p.uid' in 'where clause'